# What is the exact mathematical method to stack more than 3 images to RGB?

Tags: image, rgb

I have a simple question. If I have, for example, 6 images, how can I stack them to the nicest possible color image (RGB) image.
Dimensional reduction is not an option, as I certainly have more than 3 independent components.

RGB+CMY is also not an option, as I will ruin some of the initial data, plus R and C can be complementary.
After searching astronomical software I still have not found the solution as all of them have an option "choose your own combination of colors according to artistic preferences".

Comment: Please add a [mcve] so we can take a look and try to help you.

Comment: Are you searching for the name of a *mathematical method*?

Comment: If you are trying to represent 6 greyscale images as a single RGB images, there is no "mathematically exact" method. What you are doing is a dimensionality reduction, like it or not.

Comment: Are you trying to create a scientific image where each color channel represents some value (such as element abundance in some fake-color astronomical images)? If so, what are the six channels and how are they related (or correlated)?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You need to provide context (what are you trying to do?) and a clear desired input and output of the program for us to understand what you want :)

Comment: IMHO, the *"normal"* method of dealing with multi-spectral images is to do a Principal Components Analysis then assign RGB channels to components according to taste... https://engineering.purdue.edu/~jshan/publications/2002/SaLIS_2002_HyperImagesPCA.pdf

Comment: This was my first idea, but PCA on something that is already analysed is just too much math on poor images :(.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody. Whole story goes like this. I had multi-spectral set of images. After doing some methods for dimensinality reduction, there were 4-6 pure images. The problem now is how to make a composite image with those 6 grayscale images.

I can merge them as, for example: blue, yellow, green, orange, purple...And after some playing say that it looks nice.
But my question is if there is a mathematical rule what colors will give me the best looking image (with best contrasted details in various colours).